# Google Cloud Storage API: How do you call `create_bucket()` with storage class and location options?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I want to create a bucket equivalent to this

`gsutil mb -c regional -l us-east1 gs://my-bucket`:

how do I do that with the python API?

```
bucket = client.create_bucket('my-bucket')
assert isinstance(bucket, Bucket)
# <Bucket: my-bucket>
```

see: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set the region or the storage class through the python API. I recommend creating a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for this.